# Can't insert data using sql server 2012 stored procedure and codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Everytime i tried to insert data using a SQL server 2012 Stored Procedure in codeigniter it throws me the same error message:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 07002/0
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT erróneo o error
>   de sintaxis
>
> spa_insert_enterp ?,?,?,?,?
>
> Filename:
>   C:/Apache24/htdocs/sys_credenciales/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

That could be translated to: "**sql server - COUNT field incorrect or syntax error**"

Heres my CodeIgniter controller code:

```
public function agregar_empresa(){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');
    $cur_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $datetime_variable = new DateTime();
    $datetime_formatted = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sp="spa_insert_enterp ?,?,?,?,?";
    $result=$this->db->query($sp,$_POST['nm_rs_empresa'],$_POST['nr_rut_empresa'],$_POST['nm_desc_empresa'],$_POST['nm_rubro'],$cur_date);
    //$query = $this->db->query(      "verificacion_fechas '".$codigo."',".$estado.",'".$llave_maestra."','".$fecha_actual."'");

}
```

Here is my Stored Procedure code:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spa_insert_enterp]( 
@nm_rs_empresa_in varchar(50),@nr_rut_empresa_in varchar(30),@nm_desc_empresa_in varchar(100),@nm_rubro_in varchar(20),@fc_empresa_in datetime
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET NOCOUNT ON;






insert into empresa
(nm_rs_empresa,nr_rut_empresa,nm_desc_empresa,nm_rubro,fc_empresa)
values
( @nm_rs_empresa_in,@nr_rut_empresa_in,@nm_desc_empresa_in,@nm_rubro_in ,@fc_empresa_in);


commit transaction;
```

I tried with the both date type variables in the code, but nothing happened.
Thank to you in advance.

Comment: Did you try calling stored procedure from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to make sure the stored procedure works OK?

Comment: @Tak yes, and everythig is fine there

Comment: Try Profiler to capture the stored procedure call

Comment: I have finally have a solution for my problem. The main issue was that the regional settings (spain/spanish) of my server only accept the dates in "d-m-Y H:i:s" at the moment of insertion instead of "Y-m-d H:i:s" that i was using.

Comment: I can't post the full answer because i'm blocked to do it because weird reasons